# Add Default sorting on table in material UI ASC and DESC is working but not sorting to original order

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using TableSortLabel in material UI and i am able to do ASC and DESC order but the data should be sort in original order as well which i am unable to find i just used the default code of material ui table with TableSortLabel. Need help to reorder to original order after ASC and DESC.